# How to custom Key Name in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am need custom key name in firebase database this my code

```
  firebase.database().ref("chat").child('aaa')
    firebaseRef.push({
        text : 'bbb'
    })
```

result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NirQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store data under custom key name (however, you'll have to verify the uniqueness of that key yourself).
Your code will look something like -

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("chat").child('aaa').child('ccc');
firebaseRef.set({
   text : 'bbb'
});
```

You can further read up on this at [Firebase Realtime database - Read and Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).
This will give you the structure that you want (as per your image).

Answer (score 1):

To have it like your image you can do this, just add a new child where to store your text and remove `.push` since that will push randomly generated value to store the text

```
   firebase.database().ref("chat").child('aaa').child('ccc')
        firebaseRef.set({
         text : 'bbb'
});
```